# How can I replace * to #* with bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed

I need to deactivate certain lines in a file that starts with `*` by putting `#` at the front of the line.

At first, `sed -i 's/*/#*/g' tmp.conf` seems to work. But it adds `#` as many as I run the command.

```
user@host:/etc/security/limits.d:$ cat tmp.conf
#*          soft    nproc     4096
root       soft    nproc     unlimited

user@host:/etc/security/limits.d:$ sudo sed -i 's/*/#*/g' tmp.conf

user@host:/etc/security/limits.d:$ cat tmp.conf
##*          soft    nproc     4096
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

So it has to ignore when the line starts with `#`, otherwise put `#` at the front.

I searched to come up with `sed -i 's/^(?!#)\*/#*/g' tmp.conf`, which doesn't work.

What regex should I use to find `*`, not `#*`?

Or is there any other way to do this other than using `sed`?

Comment: `(?!...)` is a PCRE extension; it's not available in POSIX BRE or ERE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe with this?

```bash
sed 's/^\*/#&/'
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy are you sure? The question starts with "_I need to deactivate certain lines in a file that starts with * by putting # at the front of the line._"

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you're right. Rereading, you're _certainly_ right.

Comment: Why is there a `&` character in your proposed code?

Comment: @Eureka, the `&` causes the `*` to be reproduced after the `#` so we're just adding a comment character _before_ the asterisk instead of removing the asterisk

Comment: `&` in the replacement part means "all that what was matched by the regex part"

Comment: Wonderful, I didn't know we could do that! I learn something new on here every day. (I would have used capture groups blah blah, but this is more efficient!)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{^[*]}{#*}' test.txt
```

It will not add extra `#` characters to lines that already have one. And it can be run multiple times on the file, and it will not add extra `#` characters.

Example:

```
$ echo "*1\n#*2\n3" > test.txt
# cat test.txt
#*1
#*2
3
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's{^[*]}{#*}' test.txt
$ cat test.txt
#*1
#*2
3
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`s{^[*]}{#*}` : replace a literal `*` at the beginning of the line (`^`) with `#*`. Note that `*` has a special meaning (0 or more repetitions of the preceding character) and must be either escaped like so: `\*` or placed inside a character class like so: `[*]`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)